# Xamarin.Form.Maps runs into Breakpoint (simple code)

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms

I have a Xamarin Forms portable project. I simply want to show a map with Xamarin.Forms.Maps. I have created a XAML file ("MapPageXAML.xaml"). The XML itself is as following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:maps="clr-namespace:Xamarin.Forms.Maps;assembly=Xamarin.Forms.Maps"
    x:Class="MapDemo.MapPage">
  <StackLayout VerticalOptions="StartAndExpand" Padding="30">
    <maps:Map WidthRequest="320" HeightRequest="200"
        x:Name="MyMap"
        IsShowingUser="true"
        MapType="Hybrid"
        />
  </StackLayout>
</ContentPage>
```

In the MapPageXAML.xaml.cs file I have inserted a [snippet](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/user-interface/map/) (under the section 'Using Maps') from the Xamarin example pages into the constructor:

```
using Xamarin.Forms;
using Xamarin.Forms.Maps;

namespace finderbackend
{
    public partial class MapPageXAML : ContentPage
    {
        public MapPageXAML()
        {
            var map = new Map(MapSpan.FromCenterAndRadius(new Position(37, -122), Distance.FromMiles(0.3)))
            {
                IsShowingUser = true,
                HeightRequest = 100,
                WidthRequest = 960,
                VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.FillAndExpand
            };
            var stack = new StackLayout { Spacing = 0 };
            stack.Children.Add(map);
            Content = stack;
        }

    }
}
```

The 'MainPage()' of the Windows 8.1 App is as follows:

```
    public MainPage()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();

        LoadApplication(new finderbackend.App());

        Xamarin.FormsMaps.Init("[my key...]");
    }
}
```

For testing, I ran the UWP. The debugger now runs into

```
if (global::System.Diagnostics.Debugger.IsAttached) global::System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Break();
```

The var **e** tells me the following stacktrace:

```
   at System.StubHelpers.HStringMarshaler.ConvertToNativeReference(String managed, HSTRING_HEADER* hstringHeader)
   at Bing.Maps.Map.set_Credentials(String newCredentials)
   at Xamarin.Forms.Maps.WinRT.MapRenderer.<OnElementChanged>d__3.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncMethodBuilderCore.<>c.<ThrowAsync>b__6_0(Object state)
   at System.Threading.WinRTSynchronizationContext.Invoker.InvokeCore()
```

Can someone image what the problem is? I have no idea. Im sure that the error occurs after the last line 'Content = stack;' in the constructor. And I don't have more code...

Comment: call the Forms init and Maps init *before* you call LoadApplication

Comment: What is the message of the exception **e** ?